# how to add a DIV to an A href to expand the menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have a menu in html with a dropdown menu

```
                  <li class="rd-nav-item dropdown shown show">
                <a class="rd-nav-link" id="dropdownmenuheader" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"> Test drop down</a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/test">test</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/test1">test1</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/Test2">test2</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/test3">test3</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="/test4">test4</a>                    
                </div>
              </li>
```

The menu is by default not expanded (dropdown options not shown)

In the website I would like when they click on the button that the dropdown menu will expand

The code what I now use and is not working is:

```
<a class="button button-primary button-lg" href="dropdownmenuheader">Click to expand the dropdown menu from the header</a>
```

Comment: Did you forget to add the `data-toggle` to the link? Also check if the id exists on your dropdown element. Lastly please make sure Javascript is working without problems.